# Response.RedirecttoRoute going in loop when use in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, global-asax

Here is my Route

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "MyRoute",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{UserId12}",                           // URL with parameters
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Logout", UserId12=UrlParameter.Optional });

}
```

calling my route in Application_AcquireRequestState

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    short id = 4;
    Response.RedirectToRoute("MyRoute", new { UserId12 = id });
}
```

Is my route is correct? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you call RedirectToRout method in Application_AcquireRequestState? This will make all the requests get redirect to that specific route. For example all http requests made the the specific application.

Comment: Actually i have some conditions in Application_AcquireRequestState when these conditions met only then this code executedm,therefore it doest not redirect on every request. @Shiham

Comment: In that case check for the logics. Because each request for images, stylesheets, scripts witll go thorough Application_AcquireRequestState and and if any of those request for above resources does not meet the logics you have specified will make a infinite loop of redirections.

Comment: Actually it is working with Response.redirect("Path",False) but not working with Route.